# Error checking is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript and am having some issue with the following script. Seems like I have not declared the functions. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”
    “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<head>
  <title>Chapter 7: Example 4</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function btnCheckForm_onclick() {
        var myForm = document.form1;

        if (myForm.txtAge.value == "" || myForm.txtName.value == "") {
          alert("please complete the form");
          if (myForm.txtName.value == "") {
            myForm.txtName.focus();
          } else {
            myForm.txtAge.focus():
          } else {
            alert("Thanks for completing the form");
          }

        }

        function txtAge_onblur() {
          var txtAge = document.form1.txtAge;
          if (isNaN(txtAge.value) == true) {
            alert("please enter a valid age");
            txtAge.focus();
            txtAge.select();
          }
        }

        function txtName_onchange() {
          window.status = "Hi " + document.form1.txtName.value;
        }
  </script>

  <body>
    <form action="" name="form1">
      Please enter the following details:
      <p>
        Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtName" onchange="txtName_onchange()" />
      </p>
      <p>
        Age:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtAge" onblur="txtAge_onblur()" size="3" maxlength="3" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Check Details" name="btCheckForm" onclick="btnCheckForm_onclick()">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when checking for equaliy use === might be better in JS. for instance 1 == '1' will return true but 1 === '1' will return false

Comment: Can you format your code properly? with the provided text it's normal that you get errors. For instance, you don't have a initial `<script>` tag.

Comment: All good actually, found some typos and it corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors

```js
  function btnCheckForm_onclick() {
        var myForm = document.form1;

        if (myForm.txtAge.value == "" || myForm.txtName.value == "") {
          alert("please complete the form");
          if (myForm.txtName.value == "") {
            myForm.txtName.focus();
          } else {
            myForm.txtAge.focus();
          } }
    else {
            alert("Thanks for completing the form");
          }
        
    }

        function txtAge_onblur() {
          var txtAge = document.form1.txtAge;
          if (isNaN(txtAge.value) == true) {
            alert("please enter a valid age");
            txtAge.focus();
            txtAge.select();
          }
        }

        function txtName_onchange() {
          window.status = "Hi " + document.form1.txtName.value;
        }
```

```html
    <form action="" name="form1">
      Please enter the following details:
      <p>
        Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtName" onchange="txtName_onchange()" />
      </p>
      <p>
        Age:
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="txtAge" onblur="txtAge_onblur()" size="3" maxlength="3" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Check Details" name="btCheckForm" onclick="btnCheckForm_onclick()">
    </form>
```